# CSS IE 7 block element not 100% width

Tags: css, internet-explorer, width, block

I am busy to make a layouts works right in IE 7 but i am stuck with a block element and IE 7.

Here is a example: http://jsfiddle.net/mvUNz/

This is working for all browsers right but in Ie 7 the progressbar is not 100% width?

Can somewone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There fixed it for you: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvUNz/43/)

Compare with your previous code - you had way to much unneeded floats - float only when it is really needed, I cleaned the code out from unnecessary stuff. Otherwise the problematic was `float:left` in `.small`.

*edited.

Comment: I need that float left @ the small because i have multiple boxes next to each other...

Comment: @Maanstraat - Than don't use *width:auto since that is a hack for IE7 - set it to be 25% - btw your sample is showing only one box.

Comment: The problem is that IE 7 fails with the 100% with of the layout when i put 4 small boxes with 25% width next to each other. With this solution the boxes will alwasy standing nicely next to each other. Thats why i use that hack.

Comment: @Maanstraat - seeing it now - basicaly this code is enough to reproduce the bug - http://jsfiddle.net/qFREQ/1/ in IE7. Notice if you drag to make your browser window width bigger the last floated div will keep jumping up and down. This is because IE does round the percantage to a ful pixel since you can't have half a pixel and sometimes the summary of the pixel total get's over 100% which makes the last div drop down.

Comment: I would do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mvUNz/43/ - it won't be pixel perfect in IE7 but atleast it works all as it should - and most users won't even notice that - IE7 users don't appriciate beauty anyway IMO.

Comment: Your right i have changed it to: *width : 24.97%; then it is only 1px that fails when you put 4 boxes next to each other and with i can live! Thank you for your help! :-)